# How to do nested loop in python list

Tags: python, loops, arraylist, data-structures, nested-loops

```
operation = ['add','subs']
num_list1 = [[2,4],[7,4],[8,4]]

def calc(op, x,y):
    if op=='add':
        return x+y
    elif op =='subs':
        return x-y

def preview():
    result =[]
    for x,y in num_list1:
        for op in operation:
            result.append([op, calc(op,x,y)])    
    return result


result_preview = pd.DataFrame(preview())
result_preview
```

**And The output I get is:**

0. [add, 6]
1. [subs, -2]
2. [add, 11]
3. [subs, 3]
4. [add, 12]
5. [subs, 4]

**But I want the output to be like:**

0. [add, 6, 11, 12]
1. [subs, -2, 3, 4]

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do a one-liner comprehension without even having to define a `calc()` function:

```
output = [[op] + [x + y if op == "add" else x - y for x, y in num_list1] for op in operation]
```

Then you can print the inner lists:

```
for l in output:
   print(l)
```

Comment: Also, I think a list comprehension is quicker than a `for` loop in general, in python. This can be tested through use of the %timeit magic function.

Comment: @BenWS That's generally true, since even if list comps still do bytecode level loops, they don't have to lookup the list and call `list.append()` at each iteration.